# Create table as select with parameter using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to use jdbcTemplate to create table based on another table under condition. I have postgres database. When I execute this and pass parameter:

```
String SQL = "create table test as (select * from users where countryId =?)";


jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, new Object[] {3})
```

I receive table test with all columns from users table but with no rows.

However, when I execute this:

```
String SQL = "create table test as (select * from users where countryId =3)";


jdbcTemplate.update(SQL)
```

I receive test table with rows where countryId = 3, so that is what I was expecting to receive in the first solution.

Comment: Try `jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, 3)`

Comment: I doubt that you can use parameters with `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`. Split it in to `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below approach as well:-

jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_tmp (id INT NOT NULL)");

```
List<Object[]> employeeIds = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer id : ids) {
    employeeIds.add(new Object[] { id });
}
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO employee_tmp VALUES(?)", employeeIds);
```

Here you may query with 2 operations to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are using method `update` from `jdbcTemplate` in a wrong way.

Try with this:

```java
String SQL = "create table test as (select * from users where countryId = ?)";
jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing of the bind variable is not correct, but it does not play any role.

You simple *can not* use a bind variable in a *data definition statement* as you immediately see in the triggered error

```
Caught: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[create table test as (select * from users where countryId =?)];
 SQL state [72000]; error code [1027]; 
ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations
```

So you have two options, either concatenate the statement (which is not recommended due to the danger of *SQL injection*)

or split the statement in two parts:

```
// create empty table
sql = "create table test as (select * from users where 1 = 0)";
jdbcTemplate.update(sql) 

// insert data
sql = "insert into test(countryId, name)  select countryId, name from users where countryId =?";
updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new SqlParameterValue(Types.INTEGER,3));
```

Note that in the `insert` statement you can see the *correct* way of passing an interger value of `3` as a bind variable.